# Generating a process tree with fork()

Tags: c, fork

I am required to create a process tree with relationships expressed as in the picture.[image: Requirement]

The problem is I must create all "nodes" in the order of the alphabet. I have gotten this far but my order is not consistent. I believe I am using `waitpid` incorrectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pid_t pidA, pidB, pidC, pidD, pidE, pidF, pidG, pidI;

  pidA = fork();
  if (pidA < 0)
  {
    perror("A");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if (pidA == 0)
  {
    printf("%d: A\n", getpid());

    pidB = fork();
    if (pidB < 0)
    {
      perror("B");
      exit(1);
    }
    else if (pidB == 0)
    {
      printf("%d: B\n", getpid());
      waitpid(pidD, NULL, 0);

      pidE = fork();
      if (pidE < 0)
      {
        perror("E");
        exit(1);
      }
      else if (pidE == 0)
      {
        printf("%d: E\n", getpid());
        waitpid(pidG, NULL, 0);

        pidI = fork();
        if (pidI < 0)
        {
          perror("E");
          exit(1);
        }
        else if (pidI == 0)
        {
          printf("%d: I\n", getpid());
        }
        else
        {
          ;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        pidF = fork();
        if (pidF < 0)
        {
          perror("F");
          exit(1);
        }
        else if (pidF == 0)
        {
          printf("%d: F\n", getpid());
        }
        else
        {
          ;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      pidC = fork();
      if (pidC < 0)
      {
        perror("B");
        exit(1);
      }
      else if (pidC == 0)
      {
        printf("%d: C\n", getpid());
        waitpid(pidF, NULL, 0); // !

        pidG = fork();
        if (pidG < 0)
        {
          perror("G");
          exit(1);
        }
        else if (pidG == 0)
        {
          printf("%d: G\n", getpid());
        }
        else
        {
          ;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        pidD = fork();
        if (pidD < 0)
        {
          perror("B");
          exit(1);
        }
        else if (pidD == 0)
        {
          printf("%d: D\n", getpid());
        }
        else
        {
          ;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    ;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output is not consistent so I think this part wouldn't help much.

```
5644: A
5645: B
5646: C
5647: D
5648: G
5650: F
5649: E
5651: I
```

Comment: You need the printed statements to be alphabetical?

Comment: Processes run in parallel. If you want parallel processes to obey a specific order, you must synchronize them. To synchronize them, you must communicate between them. This is relatively difficult, because now processes that do not have a direct parent-child relationship must synchronize beyond simple `fork()`/`wait()`. Of course this is completely useless as well, because the whole point of parallel processes is so **not** synchronize unless necessary, and thus the entire excercise is garbage.

Comment: Here's one issue: When you call `waitpid(pidD, NULL, 0);` from within the B process, `pidD` has not been defined.

Comment: @EOF, exactly.  I'd recommend setting up various pipes in the original process and use them as your interprocess communication.

Comment: @DanielWalker I'd recommend not parallelizing things that should not run in parallel.

Comment: Agreed.  However, the question is fine as a pointless "brain teaser".

Comment: @DanielWalker I need at least the process ID to increment accordingly with the children's name. Maybe I should use `sleep()` as a dirty workaround or just give up?

Comment: Using time delays to synchronize asynchronous events is a bad, **bad** idea.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a child process will have a higher PID than its parent.

Comment: @Smithienious, was my answer not sufficient?

Comment: @DanielWalker sorry about that, I must have misclicked.

Comment: Ah, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal problem here is that `waitpid` only suffices for synchronization when all of the processes are linearly related (i.e., parent process, child process, "grandchild" process, etc.).

However, your processes, as exhibited by the diagram, are not linearly related.  You can see this issue arise when you call `waitpid(pidD, NULL, 0);` from within the B process.  Not only is `pidD` not defined in this context but the D process is not a child of the B process and so `waitpid` is inappropriate.

@EOF makes a good point that trying to run multiple processes in series defeats the purpose of having multiple processes.  However, if you just want to do this exercise as a fun brain teaser, I'd recommend setting up `pipe`s in the original process and then closing the write end when the appropriate process wants to signal that it has exited.  The process that is waiting for the first process to end can call `select` on the read end.